# Oracle SQL "meta" query for records which have specific column values

Tags: sql, oracle, filtering

I'd like to get all the records from a huge table where any of the `number` columns countains a value greater than `0`. What's the best way to do it?

E.g.:

```
/* table structure*/
create table sometable (id number, 
                        somestring varchar2(12),
                        some_amount_1 number(17,3),
                        some_amount_2 number(17,3),
                        some_amount_3 number(17,3),
                        ...
                        some_amount_xxx number(17,3));
/* "xxx" > 100, and yeah I did not designed that table structure... */
```

And I want any row where any of the `some_amount_n > 0` (even better solution is to add a field in the first place to show which field(s) are greater than zero).

I know I can write this with a huge `some_amount_1 > 0 OR some_amount_2 > 0 OR ...` block (and the field names with some `case when` but is there should be some more elegant solution, isn't there?

Comment: The elegant solution is to normalize your table by having one number column. Instaed of the >100 `some_amount_X` columns, make a table with just 4 columns: `(id, somestring, X, some_amount)`

Comment: Maybe you are right @ypercube but I can't do that: don't have rights for that & can't force those who has.

Comment: If the numbers are non-negative, in the `where` clause of the `select` add all the numbers and check if the sum is `> 0`

Comment: Or write a PL/SQL block with two nested loops. The outer loop for fetching a row from the table and inner one to check the columns of the row.

Comment: That's a clever idea @Raihan but some of the number columns can be negative :-(

Comment: I'm not going to be able to do this as a full answer for lack of an oracle test environment for ya...but you can do this as a looping dynamic sql statement to normalize your table.  Create a table as id,column_name, column_value and then use a dynamic loop to load each column individually.  I can pseudo code an answer if you'd like (I've had to do it when migrating flat file databases to a MSSQL DB...same theory, but syntax will be a lil different in oracle and what I write might need soma modifications).  Let me know if you need a pseudo code answer ;)

Comment: @Tewlfth thanks, I'm intereseted!

Comment: gave it a go...my oracle syntax might be a bit off, but if you understand the log behind it you should be able to make it work.  Let me know if the answer works out, have only had it work for me in MSSQL so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Normalize the table. You said you are not allowed to. Try to convince those that forbid such a change by explaining the benefits (performance, ease of writing queries, etc).
2. Write the huge ugly `OR` query. You could also print it along with the version of the query for the normalized tables. Add performance tests (you are allowed to create another test table or database, I hope.)
3. Write a program (either in PL/SQL or in another procedural language) that produces the horrible `OR` query. (Again, print along with the elegant version)
4. Add a new column, say called `Any_x_bigger_than_zero` which is automatically filled with either `0` or `1` via a trigger (that uses a huge ugly `OR`). Then you just need to check: `WHERE Test_x_bigger_than_zero = 1` to see if any of the rows is `> 0`
5. Similar to previous but even better, create a materialized view with such a column.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a table to sort the data into something more easily read from...something simple like id,column_name,column_value.  You'll have to bear with me, been a while since I've operated in oracle, so this is heavy pseudo code at best:

Quick dynamic sql blurb...you can set a variable to a sql statement and then execute that variable.  There are some security risks and it's possible this feature is disabled in your environment...so confirm you can run this first.  Declare a variable, set the variable to 'select 1' and then use 'execute immediate' to execute the sql stored in your variable.

```
set var = 'select id, ''some_amount_' || 1  || '', some_amount || 1 || ' from table where some_amount_' || 1  || ' <> 0'
```

Assuming I've got my oracle syntax right...( pipe is append right? I believe a 3 single quote as ''' should result in one ' when in a variable too, you may have to trial and error this line until you have the var set to):

```
select id, 'some_amount_1',some_amount_1
from table
where some_amount_1 <> 0
```

This should select the ID and the value in some_amount_1 for each id in your database.  You can turn this into an insert statement pretty easily.

I'm assuming some_amount_xxx has an upper limit...next trick is to loop this giant statement.  Once again, horrible pseudo code:

```
declare sql_string
declare i and set to 1
for i = 1 to xxx (whatever your xxx is)
set sql_string to the first set var statement we made, replacing the '1' with the i var here.
execute sql
increment i
loop
```

Hopefully it makes sense...it's one of the very few scenarios you would ever want to loop dynamic sql on.  Now you have a relatively straight forward table to read from and this should be a relatively easy query from here